# android post some data every 5 min to server, even when lock screen

Tags: android, service, lockscreen

I want to post some data every 5 min to server,
but when I lock the screen, the network is offline and I'm not sure my service is running.

The connection is not only WIFI but also GPRS and 3G.

anyone solve this question?

Comment: have service running that checks connectivity first after 5 min and then update data to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [WifiLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html). The the connection will not be lost even if the screen goes dark. If you want to use 3G,look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628058/partial-wakelock-for-3g-in-android), particulary at answer by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), you should use partial WakeLock then.

Comment: Do not do this. Wifi is disabled after an idle time to favour cellular data on devices with the capability for a reason, Wifi is a large battery drain.

Comment: @slezadav   not only wifi.GPRS,3G and so on

Answer (score 1):

You should set an Alarm (using the AlarmManager), and use a WakeLock to wake the phone and perform your action when to ensure your action occurs (regardless of if the phone services are available or not).

Here is one thread about this (there are plenty of others): [AlarmManager and WakeLock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362177/alarmmanager-and-wakelock)

Contrary to other peoples opinion, this is something perfectly reasonable to do (assuming you have considered the options).

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to do something like this. You should study your situation and determine when you really need to post some data.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209639/use-android-application-class-run-a-thread-background-to-post-some-data-to-webse) one maybe help you.

Comment: It is OK to do this, assuming you have considered the options.  I can think of lots of reasonable situations, where waking the phone to communicate to a server at regular intervals is reasonable.